# Can't load audio on pygame - Pygame error when loading audio: Failed loading libvorbisfile-3.dll: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, pygame

I've been using `pygame 2.0.1` consistently for months. Today, after I upgraded to the latest version (2.1.2), I started getting this error when trying to load an audio file:

```
'pygame.error: Failed loading libvorbisfile-3.dll: The specified module could not be found'.
```

Things I have tried so far:

- Downloading the dll and copying it to `/site-packages/pygame` (it was already there).
- Downloading the dll and copying to the folder of the script being run
- Restarting the IDE
- Restarting Windows
- Reinstalling pygame
- Downgrading to pygame 2.0.1

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.9.10 and running a virtualenv through PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by uninstalling Python, installing the latest version (3.10.2), creating a new virtual environment, upgrading `pip` to the latest version (21.2.4) and then installing `pygame` via `pip`.